# Heroku:Help-How to activate a purchased domain from Web Hosting Hub to Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns

Lurker for awhile here, great site! I am using Heroku for my website app and I want it to go live on the internet, as I have already purchased my domain name from [Web Hosting Hub](http://www.webhostinghub.com/?gclid=CMWy1pDnp8ACFdGCfgodpWEAUQ) with no hosting, just the domain registration. It seems I need assistance on how to do this and have read numerous times how to do it from this place and Heroku's documentation, but I dont know how to proceed with going online with heroku etc. Note: the Gems and app are gtg for heroku as well, I made sure.

In Web hosting Hub's Account Managment Panel there's only documentation describing how to transfer a website to them as well as dns nameserver info, but nothing in it looks like how to enter the info from other descriptions. It says Primary, secondary, and then it has blanks for nameservers, that's it. I tried what I thought was right and there was an error.  I called them as well and that didn't help my situation, very polite though.

In my tutorial the author uses dnssimple and I thought about transferring it to use Heroku as their is a video on it, but I read that I cannot transfer my registration(within 60 days of creation) as I just registered the name a week ago.

Has anyone dealt with Web Hosting Hub before and switched to Heroku? I would like to be able to figure out how to deploy my app to the web.
Also, Heroku will be doing my hosting I assume therefore, I do not need to buy a hosting plan.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how 'Web Hosting Hub' control panel is, but it has to have a 'DNS Zone' or configuration zone where you can play with CNAME, A, NS, etc .. registers.

In your DNS zone you have to add a CNAME register like this:

NAME  TYPE  VALUE/RECORD
www   CNAME yourAPPName.herokuapp.com.

Keep in mind that this type of changes can take days to be ready.

Here you have your domain provider information about how to add a CNAME register.

http://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/domain-names/dns-nameserver/add-cname-record